# lock screen always toggles between two variants

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens

Galaxy nexus, CM10.1, standard lock screen/ cLock.  If I repeatedly turn the screen off and on it goes back and forth between the two screens below.  Super annoying...

[image]

[image]

**Edit to include a question mark:**

How do I make it NOT switch between the two different lock screens every time?  I just want one lock screen; the one with the calendar and weather widgets I added...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Seriously?  How do I make NOT switch between the two different lock screens every time.  I just want one lock screen; the one with the calendar and weather widgets I added...

Comment: Is the lock screen you added a second lock screen (can you swipe right to reveal it or others)?

Comment: I didn't add any lockscreens.  They both seem to be cLock.  I can swipe left and right and it tilts but does not scroll/change screens.

Comment: Nothing is changing size.  It's two different cLock layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally tracked down something official:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=48164

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think you're going to find a setting change to fix this. It's likely a bug in the ROM, or the lock screen or cLock apk(s). I'm also running CM10.1 on my phone (LG Nitro HD) and I can't even get the cLock app to change to using an analog clock (vs. the Digital). Even after multiple reboots and confirming that indeed I have the right settings in Settings->Lockscreen.

Some rudimentary net searching and you can see issues with the lockscreen on CM10.1 is not unusual.

Comment: Can it be disabled? I should also have mentioned I have a corporate security policy applied that requires a PIN to unlock.

Comment: Settings->Security->Screen Lock->None.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Lockscreen Policy installed? That's most likely the issue.

Comment: I recently tried it to FIX the problem, but it didn't help.